# $ \lim_{x \to -\infty}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x} $

Tags: limits

I have to solve the following limit
$$ \lim_{x \to -\infty}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x} $$
My solution is:

$ \lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x}= \lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}{x \cdot\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}+1\right)}=- \infty$

while the correct result is $-1$,

but I can't understand where I'm making mistakes.

Comment: $\sqrt {x^{2}+2x} =-x (\sqrt {1+\frac   2 x})$ for $x <0$.

Comment: Hint - try rationalizing the expression first, right now you have $\infty +/- \infty $ in your calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this:
$$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{(\sqrt{x^2 + 2x} + x)(\sqrt{x^2 + 2x} - x)}{(\sqrt{x^2 + 2x} - x)} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2x} - x}$$  $$ = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{2}{-\sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{x}}-1}$$ $$ = \frac{2}{-1-1} = -1 \quad [\text{as }x< 0]   $$

Comment: how did you conclude $\sqrt {1+\frac{2}{x}}$ is $-1$

Comment: hmm i don't see the connection between $x<0$ and $\sqrt{1} = -1$.

Comment: if we're working with reals, then square root function should always give a positive result.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik i think thats because it should be $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{2}{-\sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{x}}-1}$

Comment: Yeah, thanks guys. It's changed.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt {x^{2}+2x} =-x (\sqrt {1+\frac   2 x})$ for $x <0$. Now use the fact that $\sqrt {1+\frac   2 x} \sim 1+\frac 1  x+o(\frac  1 x)$ to see that  the limit is $-1$.